# How to install packages for a NodeJs Blockchain Project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, blockchain

I wanted to install a NodeJs Blockchain project locally. On installing the dependencies in the node, I am getting these error constantly

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe failed with exit code: 1        
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\Projects\blockchain\blockchain-verification-new\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I tried many things like updating visual studio and it's all components but couldn't succeed. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command `npm i -g windows-build-tools`, it will install python and other required components

Also try to update your npm config (change paths to your versions):

1. npm config set python python2.7 --global
2. npm config set python C:\Python27\python.exe --global
3. npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global
4. npm config set VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140

Comment: Do you think this is causing the error
e:\projects\blockchain\node_modules\contextify\src\contextify.cc(131): error C2661: 'v8::Function::NewInstance': no ove
rloaded function takes 0 arguments [E:\Projects\blockchain\blockchain-verification-new\node_modules\contextify\build\contextify.vcxproj]

Comment: Are you using the latest NodeJs version ?